# Pointwise convergence to a constant function on a compact space

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

I would like to show that there is no sequence of homeomorphisms of a compact metric space which converges pointwise to some constant function. However, I'm not sure this result is true; in the case there exists such a sequence I would like to see an example...

To be more precise, we have a compact metric space $K$ (which is not a single point) and I would like to know if there exists some sequence $(f_n)_n$ where $f_n : K \to K$ is a homeomorphism for each $n$, such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise where $f : K \to K$ is some constant function.

I had an idea to prove that there is no such sequence, but it doesn't seem to work perfectly... Here is my idea (perhaps it could help) :

Suppose $(f_n)_n$ is such a sequence, converging pointwise to $f : K \to K : x \mapsto y \quad \forall x \in K$ (where $y$ is some fixed point of $K$). Let $\epsilon > 0$ be such that $B(y, \epsilon)$ (the open ball centered at $y$ of radius $\epsilon$) is a proper subset of $K$. For each $n$, $f_n^{-1}(B(y, \epsilon))$ is an open subset of $K$. So $\left\{f_n^{-1}(B(y, \epsilon)) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ is an open cover of $K$ since for each $x \in K$ there is some $n$ such that $f_n(x) \in B(y, \epsilon)$. By compacity of K, there is some $N$ for which $\left\{f_n^{-1}(B(y, \epsilon)) \mid n \leq N\right\}$ covers K. This $N$ is such that for each $x \in K$, there is some $n \leq N$ for which $f_n(x) \in B(y, \epsilon)$. This somewhat looks like uniform convergence of $(f_n)_n$, but this is trivial that $f_n$ can't converge uniformly to $f$. I would like to find some contradiction here but I can't find a way to conclude...

As I already said, I'm not totally convinced there is no such sequence. However, when I try to construct an example of such a $(f_n)_n$, I can't imagine some sequence which is not such that if $f_n(x) \in B(y, \epsilon)$ for some $n$, $x$, $\epsilon$, then $f_m(x) \in B(y, \epsilon)$ for each $m \geq n$. There is no way such a sequence could do the trick, by the reasoning explained above.

Could you please help me?
Thank you in advance,

Nicolas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a hard problem, but there are in fact simple counterexamples.
Take for instance the one-point compactification of the reals, 
$K = \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$. This is metrizable, since it is
homeomorphic to a circle. You can then define
$$f_n(x) = \cases{ \infty & when $x = \infty$ \\ x+n & otherwise.}
$$
It is easy to verify that these are homeomorphisms and that
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = \infty$ for every $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Your counterexample is indeed simple, but not totally easy to find.
I would have prefered an affirmative answer, but that's not your fault :-)